# How Does a Laravel / Forge server determine which Github user gets the public key?

Tags: laravel, github, ssh, forge

On which to automatically add the Forge servers public key? From the Forge account meta tab:

> Typically, this key will automatically be added to GitHub or
>   Bitbucket. However, if you need to add it to a service manually, you
>   may copy it from here.

Typically, this is true. Our question is: *How does Forge determine which user account gets the key?*

We have several developers / user accounts on a single Github team. We'd like to configure a particular (machine) user to get all the Forge keys.

Answer (score 1):

The user that connects/grants permissions to the forge account to their github/bitbucket account is where the key gets added.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this is true, though. It's the other way around, a Forge user sets up a server then connects it to a Github repo at which point the key is added **by** Forge to **some** GitHub user.

Comment: My GitHub account has a user-level key added for every server I have provisioned with Forge because the Forge account is connected to my GitHub account. There are no keys added to individual repositories. With the exception of the repository, I think you're saying the same thing...

Comment: Yes. That makes sense when it's just you. But from a list of 6 people in an **organization**, what determines which user gets the key? One of us does, we just want to control it. I'm suspecting it's alphabetically first.